# Why Media Queries not working in Angular8

Tags: html, css, angular, media-queries, angular8

I am running an angular app on CLI version 8. Everything was working fine last time I checked my code to github and build for production. But now when I try running it on localhost there seems to be a problem. The HTML files are not picking up the media queries from the CSS files. When I write my CSS out of the media queries everything works fine but inside media queries it doesn't work.

Also, when I try inspecting on chrome, the classes are attached on the HTML tags but CSS won't show. I don't know where I did a mistake. My guess is because of some build there caused an error or because of some npm package or may be some other reason.

These are the media queries I am using:

```
/* mobiles (landscape and portrait) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 500px) {}


/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width: 550px) and (max-width: 800px) {}


/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width: 850px) and (max-width: 1024px) {}

/* bigger laptops */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1224px) { }
```

Please help me out of this situation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your media queries are on the end of your css file?

Comment: No my CSS files begin with these media queries

Comment: I hope you have the **viewport** meta tag added in your html file.
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: Yes, it's there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the help!

There seems to be some error in an npm package that I was using. Removed the package and everything is working fine as expected. The npm package that I was using was ngx-swiper-wrapper.

Answer (score 4):

Media queries should be be at the end of your css file because css is read from top to bottom. The rule that is set last, is the one that will be executed

```
/* bigger laptops */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1224px) { }
/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width: 850px) and (max-width: 1024px) {}
/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width: 550px) and (max-width: 800px) {}
/* mobiles (landscape and portrait) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 500px) {}
```

Comment: There is no CSS outside my media queries. I just tried putting them outside and it worked but when I placed my CSS inside the media queries it doesn't work

Comment: Reverse your media queries from bigger screen to smaller.I update my answer.If dosen't work try to remove the word "only"

Comment: @neerav94 Also there is empty gab between your media queries like 801->849 px and 1025->1223. There is no style for these pixels

Comment: Changed both, but  still not working :(

Actually before production build everything was working as expected but it is not working in local now

Comment: Can you create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) to test it there?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fkxvy6
There you go, but everything works fine here

Answer (score 2):

Try adding styles locally to the component. In my case, for example, global styles didn't seem to work, and adding them locally to the component itself worked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Fixed by moving style.css declaration next bootstrap in angular.json, so that my custom styles will be override bootstrap styles.

```
       "styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
```

Answer (score -2):

**Run the following command to install media-query in your project.**

1. `bower install ng-media-query`
2. `npm install ng-media-query`
3. `Download ng-media-query.js or       ng-media-query.min.js`